# Getting strange accuracy in sentiment analysis with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project in python with word2vec as an embedding method. (in my NON_ENGLISH corpus I considered every negative tweets with the 0 label, positive = 1 and neutral = 2) I have 2 questions. 
**assuming that my corpus is compeletely balance and I set 9000 tweets for train and 900 for test

> 1.8900/8900 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5896 - acc: 0.6330 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_acc: 1.0000

As you can see, the validation accuracy (val_acc) is 1.0000 !!!!!!!!

2.While val_acc is 1 my model predicts all sentences negative!! How Can I solve it?

```
nb_epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', input_shape=(max_tweet_length,vector_size)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you included *all* tweets, and not for example *only* positive tweets? If for example all tweets are positive/negative/..., then the classifier will simply learn that the result is alway positive/negative/neutral.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I'm completely sure about my corpus and I got shocked for the strange result!

Comment: It seems to be a problem of unbalanced data

Comment: @ZahraBokaee Please post the full code including the train and validation spliting, one-hot encoding labels (if you don't use sparse labels) as well as compiling and fitting the model. BTW, you mentioned you have 3 classes (negative, positive and neutral); then why the last layer has 2 units?

Comment: Please, do not post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073345/incorrect-result-for-sentiment-analysis) - edit & update your post instead!

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your question; attempting to offer a general answer here, since there are parts of your process you do not show.

> assuming that my corpus is compeletely balance and I set 9000 tweets for train and 900 for test

This is not what your output shows; the Keras output during training

> 8900/8900

clearly says that your training set consists of 8900 samples, and not of 9000 - 900 = 8100, as you claim. So, if your initial dataset is indeed 9000 samples, this leaves you with only 100 samples for the validation set. Very small validation sets are not a good idea, and in extreme cases they can lead to spurious reported accuracies, like here (notice that, not only your validation accuracy is a perfect 1.0, it is also significantly higher than your training accuracy).

Additionally to the above, I have seen similar cases when there are *duplicates* in the initial data; in such a case, a random split procedure can easily lead a sample being in the training set, while its duplicate(s) being also present in the validation set, further jeopardizing the whole process and leading to absurd results. So, **check for duplicates and remove them *before* splitting**.

Finally, as @today remarks in the comments, since you have 3 classes, your output layer should have 3 units, not 2; this *seems* irrelevant to your issue, but I am not sure it really is...